# Kibana visualization by full path

Tags: iis, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I'm trying to do a visualization (e.g. vertical bar chart) with the page requested being the x-axis. But if I create bucket type of an x-axis, setting the aggregate to Terms and "page", it splits the path by folder, file name, and extension.

For example, if the path was /images/icons/up.png, my visualization is creating a bar chart with bars for "images", "icons", "up", and "png". I want the chart to use the full path (/images/icons/up.png) for the bars.

These are from IIS logs and I don't want to include the querystring.

```
grok {
  match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{WORD:serviceName} %{WORD:serverName} %{IP:serverIP} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:page} %{NOTSPACE:uriQuery} %{NUMBER:port} %{NOTSPACE:username} %{IPORHOST:clientIP} %{NOTSPACE:protocolVersion} %{NOTSPACE:userAgent} %{NOTSPACE:cookie} %{NOTSPACE:referer} %{NOTSPACE:requestHost} %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:subresponse} %{NUMBER:win32response} %{NUMBER:bytesSent} %{NUMBER:bytesReceived} %{NUMBER:timetaken}"]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of aggregations your string field should be defined as "**not analyzed**" in elasticsearch. otherwise elasticsearch *automatically tokenizes your string field.*
In kibana when you use a terms aggregation on an analyzed field you get a warning, do you see that?

if that does not solve your problem, can you post your elasticsearch index mapping?

Comment: I quit reading the warning after it warned about performance. It went on to say that strings would be split up and to use "not analyzed". Thanks!